C Unisgned Short is output correctly with %d but Unsigned Long is not unless using %u: 2-1 K&R C Book
after testing for 2-1 Exercise I found it interesting that the output from printing the value of the unsigned long integer with %d was not correct while using %u it was - the book did not mention %u before yet so I think I am supposed to solve this exercise using solely %d;
I don't want to ask for a solution as I would prefer to come to the conclusion by myself, I just wanted to ask why short unsigned int is output correctly with %d and not the long one? It would make more sense that both wouldn't be by the definition of the type and the role of the %u in print function;
int main()
{
    unsigned long int l, k;
    int m = 0;

    l = 1;
    k = -1;
    while (m < l) {
        ++l;
    }

    while (m > k) {
        --k;
    }
    
    printf("%d %d", l, k);   /*output is 0 -1 while if changed to %u %u output is 0 4294967295*/
    
    return 0;
}

With short:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned short int l, k;
    int m = 0;

    l = 1;
    k = -1;
    while (m < l) {
        ++l;
    }

    while (m > k) {
        --k;
    }
    
    printf("%d %d", l, k);  /*output is same with %d and %u 0 65535*/
    
    return 0;
}




I tried to change the type of printed type to %u and this worked as a solution, however it still doesn't make sense since also short is unsigned but for this also %d gives the correct values as %u, unlike long int, and book did not mention yet the %u so I think it shouldn't be used;

You're using the wrong conversions (surely a sign that you're not using compiler warnings effectively).  You need to use %lu for unsigned long and %hu for unsigned short.

I see, I saw this from compiler warning as well, but the point is that if I use %d for short the output is same as if using %hu, while if I use %d for long it's not the same as %lu, so why is that?
Also one thing which makes me thing I should not use %u or %lu is that the book did not mention this way of using printf so far

If k is an unsigned integer type (which can't be negative), why do you assign -1 to it?

If int is wider than short then an unsigned short variadic argument in the printf call will be converted to int by the default argument promotions for variadic arguments. If int is the same width as short, then an unsigned short variadic argument will be converted to unsigned int. Using the correct printf specifier %hu for unsigned short or %lu for unsigned long will let printf know what the original argument type was before default argument promotion.

@Someprogrammerdude: That is a valid way to set any unsigned value to its maximum value. (All unsigned types in C wrap around)

To add to Ian's remark, the C99 standard does not guarantee that int is wider than short, only that it is at least as wide. char, short, int, long and long long can all be 64 bits wide and that will conform to the standard. This is one reason it is such a PITA to write portable C code.

If you use the wrong conversion specifier, the behaviour is undefined.  So what you see is allowable, but so is anything else.

@TobySpeight I see the point and I agree but there is also another point that the book didn't mention the %u so far, so it seems strange that I use it to me

Also another thing which I don't really get is why if instead I check for the signed values the upper limit is negative
`#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int l;
int m = 0;
l = 1;
while (l > m)
    ++l;

printf("%d", l);

return 0;
}output: -2147483648  ifl` initial value is 1 and it's supposed to increase each time it is more than 0 (so always), how it gets to -2147483648 ?

Because l = 2147483647 is greater than m = 0, so l got incremented, but 2147483648 is outside the range of values that 32-bit int can support so it "wrapped around" to the largest negative value. (This is implementation defined behavior, but is the most common behavior.)

@IanAbbott Thank you! this makes better sense now finally

The TL;DR version: Using the correct format specifier produces the correct output. Using an incorrect specifier doesn't have to produce an incorrect result.

The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011, Section 7.21.6.1, fprintf function) states:

If a conversion specification is invalid, or if a conversion
specification is not appropriate for the type of the corresponding
argument, the behavior is undefined.

So your program is invoking Undefined Behaviour which means that you should not make any assumptions.

Half of K&R is however invoking undefined behavior as well, so maybe the book is the root of the problem.

You can find the correct conversion specifications here.
The following are relevant to this question:



Type
Conversion specification




signed short int
%hd (or %d because of standard integer promotions)


unsigned short int
%hu (or %u because of standard integer promotions)


signed int
%d


unsigned int
%u


signed long int
%ld


unsigned long int
%lu



Using an incorrect conversion specification results in undefined behaviour (i.e. unpredictable code).
